# Unknown packaging: eclipse-target-definition

Tags: eclipse-rcp, tycho

I'm trying to build an application based on the Eclipse 4 RCP platform and built with Tycho. I followed the article http://blog.vogella.com/2013/01/03/tycho-advanced/ to use a PDE target definition, and the following error occurs when building my project:

```
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: eclipse-target-definition
```

My project's modules architecture is adapted from [the EclipseCon 2013 Tycho Demo](https://github.com/jsievers/tycho-demo), plus the target module:

```
- mybundle.myproject.bundle
- mybundle.myproject.bundle.tests
- mybundle.myproject.feature
- mybundle.myproject.parent
- mybundle.myproject.target
```

I'm using tycho 0.18.1, and the `pom.xml` from the `mybundle.myproject.target` module that generates the error is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>mybundle.myproject.repository</artifactId>
  <packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>
  <parent>
    <groupId>mybundle</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybundle.myproject.parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
</project>
```

For further info, the full debug log is here: http://pastebin.com/dMEckvsH

Is there something I'm missing? The `eclipse-target-definition` packaging should work with this Tycho version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem cause of the problem is in the debug output you have linked. Compare the output before the failure ...

```
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project mybundle:mybundle.myproject.target:eclipse-target-definition:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging eclipse-target-definition from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
```

... with the output of a previous, successful lookup of one of Tycho's packaging types:

```
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project mybundle:mybundle.myproject.repository:eclipse-repository:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: [ClassRealm[extension>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:0.18.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@affc70]]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging eclipse-repository from ClassRealm[project>mybundle:mybundle.myproject.parent:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
```

---

Here is what you can read from the output: The project `mybundle.myproject.target` doesn't have any build extensions (i.e. in particular not the Tycho build extension) configured. From the second line of debug output, this seems to be because the project doesn't have the parent `mybundle.myproject.parent` configured like the other modules.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I have `tycho-maven-plugin` with `<extensions>true</extensions>` in the parant POMs Plugin Management.